# How can I improve the accuracy of my fft processing?

Tags: python, numpy, fft, floating-accuracy

I completed an on-line Digital Signal Processing Course without
doing the optional programming assignments which I am attempting now
after the course is over.
Several test inputs are provided as well as the expected outputs.
My problem is that for all test cases my output figures match the
expected values exactly up to several decimal places.
After that they don't match!
For the first value for example:

```
9.065305906994007046e+01
I get:
9.065305906729875574e+01
```

And for the last (257th):

```
1.717718363464842923e+01
I get:
1.717715652594918652e+01
```

The correspondence at the beginning of the list is 9 decimal places.
By the end of the list it is down to 5 places.
I have tried different versions of fft implementations
without improvement. It looks so close that there must be a cumulative error trick I am missing?
This is the function I used (python, numpy, scipy).:

```
    def scaled_fft_db(x):
        # a) a 512-point Hann window - weigh the input data.
        N = x.size
        window = numpy.hanning(N)
        xx = x*window
        # b) Compute the DFT of the weighed input - normalized
        A = numpy.fft(xx)/N
        # c) Return the first 257 values of the normalized spectrum
        XX = abs(A[:257])
        # take the magnitude in dBs and
        # normalize so that the maximum value is 96dB.
        X = 20*numpy.log10(XX)
        X = X + (96 - max(X))
        return X
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Those values are well within the useful tolerances for practical applications. I could imagine that this is just roundoff error differences between different implementations.

Comment: Are you comparing to a theoretical value or to a different implementation?  If a different implementation, did it use the same numerical precision?  For example, did you create x using np.asarray(data, 'float32'), while the other was 'float64' or vice versa?  Are you reading the input data from a file, and was it truncated to 8 digits, but calculated with the full 16 digits?

Comment: fft is pretty accurate.  Given white noise, `x = np.random.rand(512)`, then `np.linalg.norm(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fft(x)) - x) == 7.1510584008774975e-15`.  Gaussian white noise `x = np.random.randn(512)` is slightly worse with `norm == 2.3548886213717641e-14`.

Comment: Thanks Mark and Neapolitan

Comment: I called my function like this:

        # Read the wave file provided
        rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('./data/testinput1.wav')
        # Process the data
        scaled_output1 = scaled_fft_db(data)
        #print scaled_output1[:16]
        # Write the output to a text file
        np.savetxt('my_testOutput1.txt', scaled_output1)

Three sets of input signal and testOutput signals are provided and all have the same problem described above. I am comparing ‘'my_testOutput1.txt'’ with “testOutput1.txt” for example.

Comment: Sorry I messed up the editing of this comment

Comment: Thanks Mark and Neapolitan
I am comparing my values with those in a “testOutput*.txt” file provided by the course writers.
The sample 512 tap signal is also provided. 
I am concerned about accuracy because i suspect my function would be rejected by the on-line submission process (which of course is not available now that the course is over).

Comment: I have found a file “check_assignment.py” supplied with the assignment and my function passes all checks. It calls “np.allclose(X, X_check,atol=1e-1)” so it is looking at only the first decimal place I think - absolute tolerance 1e-1. So my original problem has not been solved, but at least I can move on. Regards